# Gradle Wrapper without the jar

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am designing an enterprise wide build system, over a thousand projects in about 21 different languages so far.  We are using gradle for this and I have a problem.  We are migrating to a gitlab server and we just finished spending weeks building out systems and hooks that explicitly prevent people from committing jar files an other libraries to the source repo.  (big long story why, you don't really care anyways).

Now the problem

How do we use the gradle wrapper without a jar file in the `gradle/wrapper` folder?  I tried deleting the folder, exactly as the git hooks will do and the `gradlew` gives us a class not found error, as I would expect.

Is it possible to use the wrapper without the jar or would the users have to regen the wrapper when they clone the project?  Can the `gradlew` file be setup to automatically regen if the `gradle/wrapper` folder or the jar is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically, when you setup *wrapper* via

```
gradle wrapper
```

you put:

- scripts
- properties
- gradle wrapper jar file

into current project directory. The `gradle-wrapper.jar` comes from your local Gradle distribution. [You can check this in the source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/build-init/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/wrapper/Wrapper.java)

```
URL jarFileSource = Wrapper.class.getResource("/gradle-wrapper.jar");
if (jarFileSource == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Cannot locate wrapper JAR resource.");
}
GFileUtils.copyURLToFile(jarFileSource, jarFileDestination);
```

When you run `gradle wrapper` you invoke the main class from that jar in order to download and run Gradle. So technically, you could modify the SH and BASH scripts to download the wrapper file from GitHub repository prior Java execution, obviously only if the file isn't present. I actually did it and it worked, however I can't be sure how error prone it may be. I don't know if GitHub won't change URL for instance in the future. I just added the following snippet somewhere in `gradlew.sh` before the `CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` line.

```
if [ ! -f "gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar" ]
then
     curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradle/gradle/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar -o $APP_HOME/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
fi
```

Anyway, the wrapper file has 56K and it was designed to be as small as possible, to allow people to put it into Git repositories. That being said,  I believe you shouldn't be worried about it and just add this particular JAR file to whitelist to your hooks and allow it in the repository.

Comment: Thanks, i will give this a shot.  We will be distributing from our own internal dist server so that may work.  Ill read the wrapper script a bit as well, maybe i can port it to something.  Another idea that came up was a clone hook that detected if the gradlew file was in there and regened it on clone.  I will play, see what it does.  And we specifically designed our jar filter system with no white list as they have a long and distinguished habit of being abused around here.

Answer (score 0):

The `gradlew` script depends on `gradle-wrapper.jar` as it simply calls *GradleWrapperMain* from the JAR. So you cannot use the wrapper script without the JAR. However, you can "bootstrap" the wrapper using [this script](https://github.com/sschuberth/dev-scripts/blob/master/android/gradlew_bootstrap.sh).